# Set Node options when running with Angular-CLI

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli

The application return 400 because it has 3 cookies, about `4k bytes` each. I am trying to set the `max-http-header-size` property when running the application with `angular cli`. (`ng serve`)

The application works as expected when running in production.

**Technologies:**

```
angular CLI: 8.1.3
asp.net core 2.1.3
```

Tried running `node --max-http-header-size=14000` but it does not work.

Comment: ASP.NET Core Version and startup method may be useful. The new templates (ASP.NET Core 2.2) simply pass through to nodejs, so everything you set up is same. Look in your `package.json` file in the `scripts` section, there should be a `start` section with the commands (and parameters) that get run when you start the application

Comment: But on a more serious note, you should fix your application. 3x4k cookies is prohibitive. These have to be uploaded at every single time you send a request, causing not only unnecessary bandwidth and lowering the response rate of your application, so the users feel its "slowiness". Are these JWT tokens packed with dozens of claims? If you you are doing it wrong, JWT claims should be small enough. Consider using Reference (aka opaque) tokens, which is just an ID and obtain the claims server sided. Also, authentication != authorization, permissions dont belong to identity/access tokens

Comment: Yes, I know about the commands in the package.json, but not sure how I would set the header size limit in there. The cookie contains a jwt, generated by an external API. If I don't store them in the encrypted cookie I would need to validate it on each call, which would add some extra complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution would be to set the value of the max header size before calling the ng serve function: `node --max-http-header-size=100000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve`

If you are using ASP.NET Core, this can be added in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max-http-header-size=100000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build": "ng build"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new templates (ASP.NET Core 2.2) simply pass through to nodejs, so everything you set up is same as w/o ASP.NET Core.

You'll know if you use the new or old templates by looking in your `Startup.cs`. If there is an `app.UseSpa(spa => { ... });` line you're using the new packages and SPA approach, where ASP.NET Core simply pipes everything to the nodejs server that starts with the application.

Look in your `package.json` file in the `scripts` section, there should be a start section with the commands (and parameters) that get run when you start the application, something like

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
  "build": "ng build --extract-css",
  "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

Comment: Still, how is the header size limit set?